# Should I remove comments in the .ini files in Grafana?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, grafana, jsonnet

I am trying to work on Grafana as code. And I have installed Grafana on my windows 10 machine. Now I wnat to configure Grafana in the Configuration files. This page ( [Grafana Configuration](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/))
says that I have to uncomment all the ini. files. But somethings are not necessary. Should I still uncomment every line? thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uncomment. There are default values usually. For example Grafana port 3000.

You need to uncomment only if you want to change those default values. For example if you want to use different Grafana port, e. g. 5000.